# Choose PHP variable's value depending on array content

Tags: php, arrays, variables

My goal is to take the language file according to the existence of the variable's value in the array and substitute with English in case it is not. Here is the code I wrote from scratch:

```
if(strpos($trns, $lng) === FALSE) {$trn = 'en';} else {$trn = $lng;}
include_once $trn.'.php';
```

where `$trns` is the array with language prefixes of existing translation files, `$lng` is the variable which holds the prefix that should be used in case it exists in the array and `$trn` is the selected prefix.

In my opinion in the human language this code reads like *in case `$lng` is `fr` but there is no `fr` in the array then use `en` for `$trn`. Otherwise use `fr`*.

`Print_r($trns)` output is `Array ( [0] => en [1] => de )`.

So the above code successfully uses the en.php file in case there is `en` in the array and `$lng = en`, the same for `de`.

But it also uses `fr` in spite of the fact there is no `fr` in the array, while it should substitute `fr` with `en` in such case.

I need your help in tracking the error I've made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strpos` does not work with arrays. Use `in_array` function.

```php
if (!in_array($lng, $trns)) {
    $trn = 'en';
} else {
    $trn = $lng;
}
include_once $trn.'.php';
```

or shorter

```php
$trn = in_array($lng, $trns) ? $lng: 'en';
include_once $trn.'.php';
```

Comment: It works, thanks a lot! Marked as the answer. But what was the mistake I've made in my code?

Comment: `strpos` does not look into arrays but in strings.